# How to make website working in kali linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, ping

I have given the name of adapter `Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller` but whenever I ping it with `ip address` it works but giving website, it gives me message `ping: google.com: Name or service not known`. In wireless adapter it works. How to deal with it?

Comment: So you can ping your own ip address, can you also ping the outside world? (for example can you ping 8.8.8.8). Then have you set a DNS in /etc/resolv.conf ? ( this resolves the web address google.com to its ip address.

Answer (score 1):

When using the wired controller, make sure that you (or your DHCP server, if you're using DHCP) configure a DNS nameserver address that is both reachable and functional as a DNS resolver server.

It looks like your wired network configuration either includes no DNS server address at all, or the configured DNS server for the wired network is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your dns-server to '/etc/resolv.conf' file.

Example:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And try to ping via name after that.